# Resharper installed, now no automatic code prompts in immediate window

Tags: resharper

I've become accustomed to using ReSharper, so uninstalling it is not an option.

However 1 little thing that I would like to try fix is the immediate window, I used to get automatic intellisense prompts when for example typing myObject.

That seems to no longer be working (and only in immediate window while debugging) since I installed ReSharper. Any ideas on how to get it back?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you're using the ReSharper intellisense (instead of the Visual Studio one), it won't work. I remember reading somewhere that this is a known issue due to a limitation in the Visual Studio extensibility API. This also affects the watch dialog.

The only thing you could do is manually invoke intellisense each time using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. Perhaps this issue will be solved in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at least I am not the only one who has noticed it.

Comment: This still doesnt work in Resharper 6 in VS2010 or Resharper 7 in VS2012

Comment: Nor VS2012 + RS8. You'd think that 4 years later JetBrains and/or Microsoft would have remedied this.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is ReSharper and there is no current any solution.

And the shortcut for intellisense-pop is Ctrl + Space, (not Ctrl + Alt + Space)