# Visual Studio Watch and Immediate window stopped automatic intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

My watch and immediate window has stopped showing intellisense options automatically until I press Ctrl + Space.

I tried to search any option to enable it again, but couldn't find one.

I am using ReSharper with my Visual Studio 2010, is it something because of it, although I don't remember it stopped working after ReSharper or even before that.

Can anybody please help!

Comment: Does automatic IntelliSense work in QuickWatch? Which ReSharper version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known issue. If you enable resharper's intellisense then intellisense won't work in immediate window:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063066/resharper-installed-now-no-automatic-code-prompts-in-immediate-window)